# Unidentified .net form control

Tags: .net, winforms

Can any of you identify the type of control I'm about to describe?

It's a sort of progress timeline with discrete labeled stages, often used during the installation of applications/operating systems. Usually a bar stretching across the full width at the bottom of the dialog, with the discrete steps marked as small bubbles along the bar.

I'd really like to use something like this for my own application but I don't want to create a custom control if one exists already.  I'm struggling to Google it as I don't know what to call it!

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: How is your MS Paint-fu a-doin'? One picture definitely worth a thousand words here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check Google Images for 'step progress bar' and you will lots of examples.

There is no doubt a control available somewhere that does one of these for you. There are various kinds of step progress bars, as you can see.

http://www.google.co.uk/search?um=1&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1920&bih=1081&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=step+progress+bar&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

Examples:

[Example 1 http://www.derby.gov.uk/NR/rdonlyres/C18B8524-8F86-4E54-BA32-3038245F8E90/0/progressBar_step1.jpg](http://www.derby.gov.uk/NR/rdonlyres/C18B8524-8F86-4E54-BA32-3038245F8E90/0/progressBar_step1.jpg)

And:

[image: Example 2]
<sub>(source: [yimg.com](http://l.yimg.com/a/i/ydn/patterns/examples/progressbar-example.gif))</sub>

And:

[Example 3 http://www.gamedevelopersweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/ProgressBar_step2.jpg](http://www.gamedevelopersweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/ProgressBar_step2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Of the built in controls the ProgressBar [image] is the closest control to what you describe.

But if you want anything fancier than that you are going to have to roll your own or purchase a third party control.

Answer (score 0):

The TrackBar?

[trackbar? http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/3817/20110519224310.png](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/3817/20110519224310.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could acheive this effect by using a standard ProgressBar in "Blocks" mode, and then overlaying the bubble images on top of it. With the bubbles on top, you probably wouldn't even need the block mode part, though. Let's say you have five steps you want to track, each one would be 20%. Space your images evenly along the length of the ProgressBar, and just change the value in 20% increments. It should look like you want.